# Remove duplicates array elemets using Script mediator in wso2 esb

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to remove the duplicates using the wso2 esb script mediator. I'm using WSO2 ESB to create a proxy service for a designated end point which needs to return a transformed JSON array. I've setup a proxy service with a foreach mediator and payloadfactory in the out sequence. The result is Failed to Publish Environments
Production and Sandbox:Error in updating the sequence at the Gateway. The result is that only the final element is returned.

I have an json object with and array of repeating elements

**Original endpoint returns something like this:**

```
{
  "colors": [
    "Red",
    "Blue",
    "Red",
    "Yellow",
    "White",
    "Yellow"
  ]
}
```

**Required results:**

```
{
  "colors": [
    "Blue",
    "Red",
    "Yellow",
    "White"]
}
```

**My mediation policy:**

```
<sequence
    xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="legalCost">
    <!-- Used to extract the elements from the JSON payload and then assigns them to the variables $1 and $2 respectively. First argument is assigned to the variable $1 and the second to $2-->
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <!-- Here you specify the format of the json message you need to output -->
        <format>
                            {
                              "products": $2
                            }
                        </format>
        <foreach expression="///jsonArray/jsonElement"" name="JSONPayload" evaluator="json">
            <!-- REturns all <foreach expression="$.policyItemSummary.[?(@.productLine)]" evaluator="json"/> -->
            <script language="js">
                <![CDATA[
                    var payload = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload");
                    results = payload.results;
                    response = new Array();
                    for (i = 0; i &lt; results.length; ++i) {
                        if (response.indexOf(payload[i]) === -1) {
                            response.push(payload[i]);
                        }
                       }
                    mc.setPayloadJSON(response);
                    ]]>
            </script>
        </foreach>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="json" expression="get-property('response')"/>
        </args
    
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: use this: `[...new Set(<paste your array here>)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's revamp the mentioned mediation sequence a bit to achieve your requirement. Given below is an extract of the mediation sequence to read the response payload and set it back after filtering

```xml
<property name="JSONPayload" expression="json-eval($.)" />
<script language="js">
    <![CDATA[
        importPackage(Packages.java.util);
        var log = mc.getServiceLog();
        
        var response = mc.getProperty("JSONPayload");
        var jsonPayload = JSON.parse(response);
        var colorList = jsonPayload['colors'];

        filtered = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < colorList.length; ++i) {
            if (filtered.indexOf(colorList[i]) === -1) {
                filtered.push(colorList[i]);
            }
        }

        // printing the elements
        // for (var i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
        //    log.info(filtered[i]);
        // }

        jsonPayload['colors'] = filtered;
        // log.info(JSON.stringify(jsonPayload));

        mc.setPayloadJSON(jsonPayload);
    ]]>
</script>
<!-- continue on setting up the response in the payload factory -->
```

Hope this helps you to achieve your requirement